# Auto-resize window widths to accomodate line length

Tags: window, window-splitting, wrapping

What is an easy way to automatically resize a window (height and or width) according to the length / line length of the buffer?

Possible behavior: A frame split horizontally with two windows with the right-hand buffer set to automatically resize to a minimum width that minimizes wrapped lines.  A maximum width might be specified and occasionally force some lines to be wrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `fit-window-to-buffer` resizes a window, so you can type `M-x fit-window-to-buffer RET` to resize the current buffer's window.
By default `fit-window-to-buffer` only resizes vertically (according to height), but you can use the variable `fit-window-to-buffer-horizontally` to change that:
- `nil` (the default): only resize vertically
- `only`: only resize horizontally (according to width)
- other value: both vertical and horizontal resizing is allowed

To resize a window programatically, you can call `fit-window-to-buffer` or hook it into appropriate places, depending on what you want to do exactly. Here are some helper functions that might be easier to use:

```lisp
(defun fit-window-to-buffer-width (&optional window max-width min-width)
  "Fit WINDOW according to its buffer's width.
WINDOW, MAX-WIDTH and MIN-WIDTH have the same meaning as in
`fit-window-to-buffer'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((fit-window-to-buffer-horizontally 'only))
    (fit-window-to-buffer window nil nil max-width min-width)))

(defun fit-window-to-buffer-height (&optional window max-height min-height)
  "Fit WINDOW according to its buffer's height.
WINDOW, MAX-HEIGHT and MIN-HEIGHT have the same meaning as in
`fit-window-to-buffer'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((fit-window-to-buffer-horizontally nil))
    (fit-window-to-buffer window max-height min-height nil nil)))

(defun fit-window-to-buffer-height-or-width
    (&optional window max-height min-height max-width min-width)
  "Fit WINDOW according to its buffer's height and width.
WINDOW, MAX-HEIGHT, MIN-HEIGHT, MAX-WIDTH and MIN-WIDTH have the same meaning
as in `fit-window-to-buffer'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((fit-window-to-buffer-horizontally t))
    (fit-window-to-buffer window max-height min-height max-width min-width)))
```